# Can't post Flask form data for testing (FieldList) [DeprecationWarning]

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-wtforms, werkzeug

I'm writing several different flask forms. So far, what I've done to test the routes that I use with those forms is.

- Creating the form object
- Populating the form
- Posting the form data

For example, this works (short version of the class):

```py
class RequestForm(FlaskForm):
    project = SelectField(label='Project', id='project', coerce=str)
    name = StringField('Environment Name', id='env_name', validators=[DataRequired()])
    requested_by = StringField('Requested By', validators=[DataRequired()])
    tag = StringField('Tag')
    required_from = DateField('Required From', format='%Y-%m-%d', validators=[DataRequired()])
    required_to = DateField('Required To', format='%Y-%m-%d', validators=[Optional()])
```

And when testing:

```
def test_post_full_request_is_correct(self):
        with self.app.test_client() as http_client:
            self.login(http_client)

        required_from = str(datetime.datetime.today().date() + datetime.timedelta(days=1))

        form = RequestForm()
        form.project.data = 'SO'
        form.name.data = 'TEST02'
        form.requested_by.data = 'dev01'
        form.required_from.data = required_from
        form.env_type.data = 'DEV'
        form.location.data = 'Narnia'
        form.size.data = 'L'
        form.resilience.data = '0'
        form.submit.data = True

        response = http_client.post('/request', data=form.data)
```

This works fine.

However, I've also got these forms. The main one being `RequestsComponentsForm`.

```py
class RequestComponentForm(FlaskForm):
    component = StringField('Name', validators=[DataRequired()])
    source = SelectField('Source', choices=[('nexus', 'Nexus')])
    version = StringField('Version')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['csrf_enabled'] = False
        super(RequestComponentForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)


class RequestComponentsForm(FlaskForm):
    components = FieldList(FormField(RequestComponentForm))
    submit = SubmitField('Request Environment')
```

It works like a charm when testing it manually. However, when I tried automated testing:

```py
c_form = RequestComponentsForm()
components = ['app-a', 'app-b', 'app-c', 'app-d', 'app-e', 'app-f']
test_versions = ['1.2.3', '3.2.1', '2.1.3', '5.7.1', '3.6.3', '1.4.6']
for c, v in zip(log_design_components, test_versions):
    entry = RequestComponentForm()
    entry.component = c
    entry.source = 'nexus'
    entry.version = v
    c_form.components.append_entry(entry)
 
    response = http_client.post('/request{0}components'.format(env_request_id),
                 headers={'Referer': good_referrer},
                 data=c_form.data)
```

I get the following:

```
venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/test.py:349: DeprecationWarning: it's no longer possible to pass dicts as `data`.  Use tuples or FileStorage objects instead.
```

I don't understand why my approach to testing the first form works and the same approach for the 2nd one doesn't.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

**Update**

This is what the first form's data looks like:

```
{
  'project': 'SO',
  'name': 'TEST02',
  'requested_by': 'dev01',
  'tag': '',
  'required_from': '2018-07-11',
  'required_to': None,
  'monday_on': None,
  'monday_off': None,
  'tuesday_on': None,
  'tuesday_off': None,
  'wednesday_on': None,
  'wednesday_off': None,
  'thursday_on': None,
  'thursday_off': None,
  'friday_on': None,
  'friday_off': None,
  'saturday_on': None,
  'saturday_off': None,
  'sunday_on': None,
  'sunday_off': None,
  'env_type': 'DEV',
  'location': 'Narnia',
  'size': 'L',
  'resilience': '0',
  'submit': True
}
```

And the second:

```
{
  'components': [
    {
      'component': 'app-a',
      'source': 'nexus',
      'version': '1.2.3'
    },
    {
      'component': 'app-b',
      'source': 'nexus',
      'version': '3.2.1'
    },
    {
      'component': 'app-c',
      'source': 'nexus',
      'version': '2.1.3'
    },
    {
      'component': 'app-d',
      'source': 'nexus',
      'version': '5.7.1'
    },
    {
      'component': 'app-e',
      'source': 'nexus',
      'version': '3.6.3'
    },
    {
      'component': 'app-f',
      'source': 'nexus',
      'version': '1.4.6'
    }
  ],
  'submit': True
}
```

They're both dictionaries, so I really don't understand why the first one would work and the other one won't.

Answer (score 1):

FieldList is a handy wrapper of a group of fields in WTF. While posting data, you should use the original form, for the second form, the payload should be as follows:

```
{
  'components-0-component': 'app-a',
  'components-0-source': 'nexus',
  'components-0-version': '1.2.3',
  'components-1-component': 'app-b',
  'components-1-source': 'nexus',
  'components-1-version': '3.2.1',
  ...
}
```

Comment: How this answer to anything? I can't even pass dict to post data anymore, something get deprecated, and further errors doesn't make sense.